# Request: Nokia SDK & Products Username & Serial

Tags: sdk, nokia

I'm Ronaldo, 1 Year ago, I was looking for Nokia products or SDKs but the site is down, there in the archive, until finally they created the Nokia Developer Tools and SDKs, there are parts 1 and 2, here the link:

Part 1: https://archive.org/details/nokia_sdks_n_dev_tools

Part 2: https://archive.org/details/nokia_sdks_n_dev_tools2

I found these products: Nokia 3410 SDK, Nokia 5100 SDK, Nokia 3510i MIDP SDK, Nokia 3300 SDK, Nokia Audio Suite, Nokia S40 DP20 SDK 1.0, 1.1 & 6255 and Etc that uses serial, Then I don't know the username and the license serial, I found the page that shows the serial of these products and I didn't find it! I wanted it so much ... Can anyone tell me what the username and serial number for all Nokia products are?

Answer (score 0):

I have some old serial numbers but it's not working for some reason (maybe the SDK tries to validate with the forum.nokia.com site that's down). But you can reset the time trial. It only works for the latest SDKs that can skip the serial number request to "remind later" during installation. Most of the SDKs have a 14-day trial that requests the serial number when the trial expires.

1. First install the desired Nokia SDK normally, skipping the serial number request when requested on screen during installation. Then open the Nokia emulators normally during the time trial.
2. After the computer reboots and before launch the emulator, open the Windows Registry and delete all the keys under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Nokia\Product Registration\`. It should reset the time trial to a new period when you launch the Nokia emulators in any next time. Repeat this step when the trial expires.

Comment: But it's works in Nokia S40 DP20 SDK 6255 1.0?